# Better way to dynamic change contents in a datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

My flights prices are listed in a table powered by jQuery DataTables.

I want to add a checkbox to change the prices dynamically: if the box checked, the prices will be added by its Airline company.

For example,

- Jetstar's prices will be added by 500
- Peach's prices will be added by 800.

When the checkbox unchecked, the prices should be rollback to the original.

Any idea how to do so?

I hope the jQuery DataTables should also works after changing prices.

I have no idea how to do it with JavaScript, just need some directions.

[image]